# pandas groupby (pivot) give the wrong results

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Iam working with file below and I tested whether pandas give the same results as Excel pivot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2RO-sL_RtQwdmtRaTRiZjZwTkE
Here is my code to groupby:

```
group=data.groupby(['IMPLT_BANK','GROUP','IMPLT_PLACE','ISSUECODE'])['ISSUELEVEL'].mean()
```

It gives me a table with 3402 rows, while the equivalent in Excel give me 3396 rows. I did some check then sadly, pandas gives me some duplicate results

Is it my error(hopefully) or pandas bug?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a bug. They are probably not duplicates, check if the number of rows changes when doing `group.drop_duplicates(subset=['IMPLT_BANK','GROUP','IMPLT_PLACE','ISSUECODE'])`

Comment: Sorry but ur code did not work, it give me a syntax error.From what I knew, in pivottable, things will be uinque?

Comment: For example, this things appears 2 times in pandas pivot 03_SME G3 G3_5000 X0401

Comment: My code is wrong, you'll need to reset the index before hand. This should work: `group_no_duplicates = group.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['IMPLT_BANK','GROUP','IMPLT_PL‌​ACE','ISSUECODE'])` I am not certain of how pivot table deals with duplicates, but for groupby the resulting rows are unique

Comment: It still did not work , too. Did u try downloading my files, pivot it and compare? The creator of pandas said that groupby, pivot table in pandas and in excel are the same things. In most of my test, they are  the same,only for this data, pandas seems to give an incorrect results.

Comment: Sorry @ducvu169, but I'm not going to get my hands dirty with your data. Best of luck

Comment: Tks for help. I found it out. The difference here is that pandas is case-sensitive while excel is not.I am very happy to find out that it is not pandas error